# Is there a way to upload the contents of a URL to Dropbox using their API?

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm building a client/server video app.  The video lives on the server, typically.  If I want to allow app users to copy videos to their Dropbox, is there any way to do that using the Dropbox API on the app other than downloading the content to the app and re-uploading it to Dropbox?  Reading their API, it seems like they only have file upload, not upload from a URL.  Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

Is the Saver an option for you? That takes a URL and presents the user with UI to choose a location within Dropbox, after which the file will be saved to that location.

It's as simple as including a `<script>` tag and then adding `class="dropbox-saver"` to what would otherwise be a normal download hyperlink.

See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver.

Comment: Does the Saver actually download the whole URL to your machine and then re-upload it to Dropbox?  If so, then no it's not an option.  If it uses a different API to actually just tell Dropbox to suck in that URL, that would be perfect (though I'd want to forego the UI and just use that internal API).

Comment: The file is pulled directly from the URL to Dropbox's servers. There's no API available for this, so if you can't use the UI, then this isn't an option for you.